# #1442Can't update table 'jyrnal_poezdok' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, триггер

Не могу понять, где ошибка в данном триггере phpMyAdmin ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле Стоимость услуг в таблице Журнал продаж не обновляется... Время совершения менял на Alter, не помогло.
В чем может быть ошибка ?

Comment: А у `jyrnal_poezdok`, случаем, нет триггера, который каскадом может менять `okazan_yclydu`?

Comment: нет такого триггера